# How do i get imdb_id from in api using foreach loop

Tags: php, api, imdb, themoviedb-api

I want to get the imdb_id from inside json using foreach
i am having an issue with getting it decoded and displayed.

My php code so far:

```
$themoviedburl = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/60625/external_ids?api_key=";
$get = file_get_contents($themoviedburl);
$decode1 = json_decode($get, TRUE);
foreach($decode1['external_ids'] as $value){
    $imdb    = $value['imdb_id'];
}
```

Json:

```
{"id":60625,"imdb_id":"tt2861424","freebase_mid":"/m/0z6p24j","freebase_id":null,"tvdb_id":275274,"tvrage_id":33381,"facebook_id":"RickandMorty","instagram_id":"rickandmorty","twitter_id":"RickandMorty"}
```

Comment: Please post error or tell  where you stuck. Your code is looking fine !!

Comment: Their documentation indicates a separate endpoint is available for that, `GET
/tv/{tv_id}/external_ids`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `$decode1 = json_decode($get, TRUE);`

You can simply do `$imdb_ids = array_column($decode1['external_ids'],'imdb_id');` to collect all `imdb_id` in one array.

More info on `array_column` : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

As discussed in the comments, to get only one `imdb_id` ID, you can do like below:

```
$json = '{"id":60625,"imdb_id":"tt2861424","freebase_mid":"/m/0z6p24j","freebase_id":null,"tvdb_id":275274,"tvrage_id":33381,"facebook_id":"RickandMorty","instagram_id":"rickandmorty","twitter_id":"RickandMorty"}';

$decoded_data = json_decode($json,true);

$imdb_id = $decoded_data['imdb_id'];
```

Comment: When i print it using print_r($imdb_ids); it shows up blank?

Comment: @Saxo_Broko Can you share the entire JSON so that I can guide you better? Also, did you consider RamRaider's comment on your question?

Comment: i updated the json to use the api endpoint that RamRaider suggested but i don't know how to get the id out of the json

Comment: @Saxo_Broko You need multiple IDs. Correct? Can you give the API URL which gets you the JSON with `external_ids` as well?

Comment: I only need 1 ID which is the imbd one and the api url is http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/60625/external_ids?api_key= the output is in the json above